# set the content of an anchorPane with fxml file

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I use the accordion control. Depending on the titled pane, I need to load a fxml file into an anchorPane. So I have two parts: one for accordion and another one for anchorPane to display contents depending on click.

```
@FXML
private StackPane tmpPane;

@FXML
private void itemMembres(MouseEvent event) throws IOException { 
    tmpPane.getChildren().add((Node)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/test.fxml")));
}
```

tmpPane is an anchorPane in the view.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution

- Create a node by loanding a fxml file
- Use setAll of `AnchorPane`

  ```
  @FXML
  private AnchorPane tmpPane

  @FXML
  private  void itemMembres(MouseEvent event) throws IOException{

  Node node;
  node = (Node)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/MembresTableau.fxml"));
  tmpPane.getChildren().setAll(node);
  ...}
  ```