# Set the content of a pane with the pane of another FXML file

Tags: fxml

My question is about the same as these two:

-[JavaFX how to inject new FXML content to current Scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567836/javafx-how-to-inject-new-fxml-content-to-current-scene?answertab=votes#tab-top)

-[set the content of a anchorPane with fxml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515954/set-the-content-of-a-anchorpane-with-fxml-file)

I could not use these answers because I don't understand both of them. 
I have two (and later more) FXML files where one functions as a 'main', which has a pane where the contents of the other FXML file should be added to.

How should I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program entry point:

```
public class App extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Parent startScreen
 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(startScreen);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

MainScreenController

```
public class MainScreenController implements Initializable{

private static AnchorPane contentBox;

@FXML
private AnchorPane paneContent;

public MainScreenController() throws IOException {
    this.paneContent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
     MainScreenController.contentBox = this.paneContent;
}  

public static AnchorPane getContentBox(){
    return MainScreenController.contentBox;
}

}
```

Then MainScreen.fxml needs to have MainScreenController as controller and also needs to contain an AnchorPane with fx:id paneContent.
Then from anywhere in your program you can call getContentBox() and use .set() to change the screen.